# Disable autostart for a service without uninstalling?

Tags: server, services, tomcat

How can I disable autostart for a service without uninstalling?  For example, I'd like to leave tomcat installed, but I don't want it turning on every time I restart.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d tomcat disable
```

Basically `update-rc.d` will modify existing runlevel links for the script `/etc/init.d/tomcat` by renaming start links to stop links.

Comment: Note that the default tomcat service name is "tomcat7" in ubuntu 14.

Comment: If your tomcat is tomcat6 you will need to do "sudo update-rc.d tomcat6 disable" else you will get error.

Comment: Weirdly, this removed the links, and then created some new ones when I did it for postgresql. Dunno.

Comment: You might want to consider this message in the `update-rc.d`: `The disable|enable API is not stable and might change in the future.`

Answer (score 43):

More generic and more visual, with a nice UI: `sysv-rc-conf`

Uncheck the boxes for tomcat7 (runlevels 2 to 5), quit and that's it.

Comment: cool, that's a tool I haven't seen before.  It was useful to confirm that the `update-rc.d` command actually had worked

Comment: This tool is great, it was the thing I was searching for. Thank you very much for it.

Answer (score 41):

The `disable|enable` API is not stable and might change in the future. I suggest you use the following command to remove all the symlinks in `/etc/rc?.d/`:

```
update-rc.d -f tomcat remove
```

Comment: This one worked for me. I had uninstalled tomcat manually yet it was trying to shut it down before any reboot. Disable without -f parameter yelded "file does not exists".

Answer (score 20):

For upstart jobs, you need to disable service like this (e.g. mysql):

```
$ sudo -s
# echo "manual" > /etc/init/mysql.override
# exit
```

or using this one-liner:

```
$ echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override > /dev/null
```

Comment: + 1 million, this is what worked for me. I was trying to stop transmission-daemon from starting on startup and the update-rc.d method *used* to work, but it looks like its been converted to an Upstart script now so this is the only method that works

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me and disabling mongodb! Couldn't seem to get it working with echo so I did it the oldschool `sudo vi /etc/init/mongodb.override` way