# How do I disable Munin?

Tags: startup

My laptop (Ubuntu 10.10) takes a really long time to start up. Watching top, one of the things it seems to be spending a lot of time on is Munin. I'm trying to sort out what might depend on it and/or how to disable it most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove it using `sudo apt-get remove munin`.

Munin is a server and network monitoring tool.  I wouldn't consider a laptop an appropriate place to install it.  As it is designed to collect data every five minutes and generate graphs of the current status, a device which is not always on is not that suitable.  Munin uses a web interface for reporting.

If you use you laptop unplugged, munin will suck a lot of power regenerating graphs every five minutes.

EDIT: `munin-node` is daemon but doesn't do anything unless it has a client.  Disabling it will just make life miserable for `munin`.

`munin` is there is not an `/etc/init.d` script or `/etc/init` configuration.  `munin` and a `munin-node` job are run every 5 minutes as `cron` jobs using files in `/etc/cron.d`.  You need to remove these files or comment out the cron entries to disable the processes.  It may be possible to disable the scripts buy giving them and extension like `.disabled`.

Comment: Very useful tip on battery usage. Not something that had occurred to me. However, I do use my laptop to test out server software locally, so it isn't crazy to have munin available.

Comment: @Amanada: Having it available, and having it running are two different things.  I believe Munin automatically configures itself in cron.  Look for munin files in `/etc/cron.d`.

Comment: Annoying that removing it didn't remove the cron jobs. Disabling them now.

Comment: @Amanda: Removing a package leaves it configured.  Cron jobs will run, but usually detect the program is missing and shutdown.  This is not great for laptops.  I think anacron can be configured not to run when you are on battery.

Answer (score 0):

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) appears to be a network monitoring tool, likely what you're seeing on start up is it preparing it's buckets for trapping and logging network connectivity. This is likely installed alongside some kind of "webhosting" control panel, etc. The default installation of the Ubuntu Desktop does not use it though. If this isn't something you use, you should be able to disable it via the commandline by removing it from the `update-rc.d`

[Disable autostart for a service without uninstalling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27134/disable-autostart-for-a-service-without-uninstalling)

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful: [Disable autostart for a service without uninstalling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27134/disable-autostart-for-a-service-without-uninstalling)

However, I realized that what I was looking for was `apt-cache rdepends munin` and `apt-cache rdepends munin-node` -- those let me establish that it wasn't a known dependency.