# What is the recommended way to disable a service in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upstart

The specific programs that I needed to disable were `nginx` and `postgresql`.

I have tried the [flagship post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) for this question, which suggests I create a manual override file for `upstart`, and it does not work for me. Why?

However, the approach described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27134/disable-autostart-for-a-service-without-uninstalling), using `update-rc.d`, does work for me.

I read that `systemctl` is the suggested approach going forward, but that tool does not exist on my version.

Comment: systemd for systemctl was introduced in ubuntu 15.04. 14.04 didn't have it yet and used initctl or service.

Answer (score 1):

Typically those services are started in any of these folders : `/etc/init` , `/etc/init.d` , or `/etc/rc.2.d` , or `/etc/rcS` .

Find the file corresponding to the service, and rename it or move to another directory where it won't run.